# Delete Groups in the middle of ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, eclipse, adapter, expandablelistview

So, I'm expanding on an ExpandableListAdapter example to display some data from a SQLite DB.  I can populate the adapter correctly with the data, display the list, and expand as desired.  The interesting behavior is when I attempt to delete a group in the list.  If I delete an item from the END of the list, the behavior is as expected, the group is removed, NotifyDataSetChanged is called correctly, and the list updates.  If I attempt to delete an item from !end of list, the app crashes with this output:

```
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882): Process:
> com.example.com.vogella.android.listview.expandable, PID: 3882 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> com.example.com.vogella.android.listview.expandable.ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLog.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLog.java:109)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1349) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1608) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 03-29 14:37:56.763:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> 03-29 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 03-29
> 14:37:56.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3882):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-29 14:37:56.783:
> D/dalvikvm(3882): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 105K, 2% free 9559K/9700K, paused
> 13ms, total 13ms
```

And adapter code below:

```
    package com.example.com.test.android.listview.expandable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLog extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final SparseArray<GroupJumpLog> groups;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Activity activity;

    private ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLogCallback callback;

    public ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLog(Activity act, SparseArray<GroupJumpLog> groups) {
        activity = act;
        this.groups = groups;
        inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        //    return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
        return groups.get(groupPosition).children.longValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //    final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        final long id = (Long) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("boners!" + this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "touched!" +
                        "",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//              deleteItem(groupPosition);
                Log.e("adapter","size = " + getGroupCount());
                groups.remove(groupPosition);
                Log.e("adapter","size = " + getGroupCount());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
//              callback.DeleteJump(groupPosition, id);

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        //    return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
        }
        GroupJumpLog group = (GroupJumpLog) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(group.string);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(!isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    public void setCallback(ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLogCallback callback){

        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public interface ExpandableListAdapter_JumpLogCallback {
        public void DeleteJump(int groupPosition, long id);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        groups.remove(groupPosition);
    }
}
```

I'm a little confused about the behavior.  Any thoughts on why this breaks when the index isn't at the end?

Any comments are much appreciated!

Comment: So, to add to this, I see that the fault is occurring in getGroupView, and so I'm wondering if this has to do with using the SparseArray for my objects in the ExpandableListView.  If I delete an object in SparseArray at a specific index, do the items re-order, or is there a null object located at that index now, and that's why getGroupView barfs?  

Is there a way to reconstruct groups if this is the case?

Comment: Not sure what the procedure is to answer my own question, but it had to do with trying to access a non-existent index in the sparse-array, after I removed that element.  I changed from SparseArray to ArrayList and now get the desired behavior without crashing.